# Reading opened Excel file by OLEDB

Tags: c#

I am using OLEDB method to read an excel file, however if the file is closed then there is no issues but if the file that has to be read is open then if i use oledb i get an error.
Any workaround for this???????
Please help....

Answer (score 1):

If you have just to read, and not to write, the file, you can just make a copy of the file and read the copy, then when done delete it.

Another solution is to use [Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa679806%28v=office.11%29.aspx#officeinteroperabilitych2_part1_excel)

Regards.